# How to use handle in multiple subs

Tags: vb.net, parent-child, handle

I'm certainly no expert on VB, so hopefully someone is willing to help me out here.
When I use the code down below, the msgbox in mybase.shown properly shows the handle number, but the one in button1.click throws the exception "No process is associated with this object". So apparently the handle is only available during the mybase.shown sub? How do I make it available for other subs too?
Thanks for any help in advance!
Kind regards, Eric

```
Option Strict On
    Public Class Form1
        Private WithEvents proc As New Process
        Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
        Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = &HF030
        Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
        Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr) As Integer
        Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
        Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
            Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("notepad")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
            SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
            SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
            MsgBox(proc.MainWindowHandle)
        End Sub
        Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            MsgBox(proc.MainWindowHandle)
            SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: You're not really thinking this through. How do you usually make a value available later? You assign it to a variable. Why are you assigning the `Process` object to a variable when the only interest you have in that is to get the window handle? Just assign the handle to a variable in the first place and forget about the `Process`. The issue is not the handle but the fact that the window is not longer the main window for the process.

Comment: 1) You should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) (and set it as the default for new projects): the declaration of `GetParent` seems to have the wrong variable types. 2) The variable `proc` declared at the class level is not the same variable `proc` declared in the sub.

Comment: Hi Andrew and User18387401,
I added Option Strict On to the example above and changed the getparent type to Long (from other examples on the Internet), but I still get the same error.
I don't really understand what you mean by "variable proc declared at the class level is not the same variable proc declared in the sub" Can you please show me how I should correct this then?
Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.
Kind regards,
Eric

Comment: The following may be helpful: [How to: Control the Scope of a Variable (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable) and [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope).

Comment: The problem is you've declared proc at the form level, then again as a local variable in the Form load event.  The 2nd declaration in Form Load will be hiding the higher level declaration which will mean it's never being set.  Kind of a little surprised that your IDE is not warning you about this as VS normally does this by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much everybody! With your help, I finally managed to make it work. I really appreciate your efforts!
Kind regards,
Eric

```
Options Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents proc As Process
    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = &H112
    Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = &HF030
    Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Dim testje As Long
    Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        proc = Process.Start("notepad")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
        SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just one little thing: there shouldn't be a `New` in `Private WithEvents proc As New Process`.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, Corrected. Thanks!